# Problems with VB code regarding Blank Input Box and error converting string "" to double

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm writing a simple VB form and so far everything is working great.  However if I leave a blank input box for "SpaceLeftText.Text" and hit enter I get this error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click, MyBase.Activated


    SpaceLeftText.Text = Math.Round((((Val(AxleLengthText.Text - 12.7) / 2) - 1.59 - 3)), 2)

    Dim count As Decimal
    count = SpaceLeftText.Text

    If count > 10 Then
        TenText.Text = Int(count / 10)
        count = count - (TenText.Text * 10)
    Else : TenText.Text = 0
    End If

    If count > 4 Then
        FourText.Text = Int(count / 4)
        count = count - (FourText.Text * 4)
    Else : FourText.Text = 0
    End If

    If count > 2 Then
        TwoText.Text = Int(count / 2)
        count = count - (TwoText.Text * 2)
    Else : TwoText.Text = 0
    End If

    If count > 1.5 Then
        OnePointFiveText.Text = Int(count / 1.5)
        count = count - (OnePointFiveText.Text * 1.5)
    Else : OnePointFiveText.Text = 0
    End If

    If count > 1 Then
        OneText.Text = Int(count / 1)
        count = count - (OneText.Text * 1)
    Else : OneText.Text = 0
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub ResetButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ResetButton.Click
    AxleLengthText.Clear()
    SpaceLeftText.Clear()
    TenText.Clear()
    FourText.Clear()
    TwoText.Clear()
    OnePointFiveText.Clear()
    OneText.Clear()
    GapText.Clear()
    QuadRingText.Clear()
    OringSpacerText.Clear()
    FitText.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

End Sub

End Class
```

so I Added the following code above Dim Count as decimal:

```
 If SpaceLeftText.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Axle Length!")
    Else
```

but now as soon as i run it, without hitting enter and leaving a blank input box I immediately get my message box saying "Please Enter Axle Length".  I hit ok and it immediately pops back up for about 14 times before going into the program. Does anyone have any input. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. 
Thank You.

Comment: I believe that is has to do with your handles MyBase.Activated.  If activated it is calling that method.  It should only handle the click event.

Comment: As well as Sorcen's very good point, you should check if `AxleLengthText.Text` can be parsed as a Double, e.g. by using `Double.TryParse`. And please use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it will stop you from writing code which the computer is free to interpret however it "feels" is appropriate, which is often not the way you intended.

Answer (score 1):

The message is appearing 14 times because your event is handling (MyBase.Activated).

Try the following instead:

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
```

Also make sure that (AxleLengthText.Text) is not empty and is valid to be converted to double value as shown below:

```
dim tmpDouble as double

if not string.isNullOrEmpty(AxleLengthText.Text) andalso Double.TryParse(AxleLengthText.Text, tmpDouble ) Then
    SpaceLeftText.Text = Math.Round((((Val(tmpDouble - 12.7) / 2) - 1.59 - 3)), 2)
end If
```